# angular js custom directive not working without the ng-app directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a custom directive named myAddress. I shall be using it in another html page. The custom directive is only working if I give it a ng-app in the element as below.

```
<my-Address  ng-app="customModule">  </my-Address>.
```

but not working if I write this

```
<my-Address >  </my-Address>.
```

I should get it working without the ng-app in the element.

The following is the custom directive code.

```
var mainApp = angular.module("customModule", ['ngSanitize', 'schemaForm']);
    mainApp.directive('myAddress', [function() {
        var directive ={};
        directive.restrict = 'E';
        directive.templateUrl = 'customDirective.html';
        directive.controller = 'myController';
        //directive.module = 'customModule';
        directive.compile = function($scope, element, attributes) {
        }
        return directive;
    }]);
```

The html where the directive is added.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html >

<head>
    <title>Angular JS Custom Directive</title>

    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<h2> some heading </h2>

    <my-Address  ng-app="customModule">  </my-Address>

<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script
        src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="customDirectiveScript.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="tv4.js"></script>
<script src="ObjectPath.js"></script>
<script src="schema-form.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-decorator.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please post the whole "html" content ?

Comment: You need to have ng-app unless you bootstrap angular by yourself.

Comment: Of course angular app will *not work* unless you bootstrap it. This is what happens then you put ngApp attribute.

Comment: How do I bootstrap it myself? any links on how to would be appereciated. 
@Zakaria which html do you want is it the customDirective.html or the html where I am using the custom directive.

Comment: @kasey the HTML where the directive is put in

Comment: It looks like you are using your `my-address` directive outside the scope of your `ng-app` if you're having one already. If not add one to the top most element you want AngularJS to be active in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

```
<!Doctype html>
<html >

<head>
    <title>Angular JS Custom Directive</title>

    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body ng-app="customModule">
<h2>NationWide Standardized </h2>

    <my-Address  >  </my-Address>

<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="customDirectiveScript.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="tv4.js"></script>
<script src="ObjectPath.js"></script>
<script src="schema-form.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-decorator.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Take a good look at the ng-app on the body tag.

If you want to use it inside another ng application. you need to inject you customModule inside this application

see this example

```
angular.module('myApp',['customModule'])
```

the custom module you wrote will be injected inside another angular application which gives you access to you my-address directive

Comment: I should not have the ng-app in my html at all because the custom directive shall be used in another angular application where the app name is different but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<html>` needs a `ng-app` attribute, if you're not going to call `angular.bootstrap()` yourself (you might want to do that for reasons related to asynchrony).

You want to put that on your top-level tag (which should be `html`), because anything outside of that won't be picked up by angular (that means controllers, views, foreaches, etc, etc).

This is why your code doesn't work: Angular is not "enabled" outside of the `ng-app`-enabled element.

Comment: where do I call the angular.bootstrap()? Do I have to call it in the js file after the directive.

Comment: I'd recommend to use `ng-app`